# How to convert eps files to png files with maintaining names?

Tags: python, linux, bash, png

In some folder on Linux I have got files *.eps and I would like to convert them into *.png with maintaining names, e.g.: ball.eps to ball.png. I tried to do:

```
convert *.eps *.png
```

but the result wasn't satisfied. To do that I need to write some simple script maybe in Python or bash, so how can I take the files name from folder, e.g. in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**edit**: if you want the filenames to be the same, I don't even think that you need a loop. You can do:

```
mkdir backup_directory && cp *.eps backup_directory
mogrify -format png *.eps
```

`mogrify` is like `convert` but it modifies files in-place, so you need to back them up elsewhere before you do this if you don't want to lose the originals.

---

Using a loop, you can do this in bash:

```
for f in *.eps; do b=$(basename "$f" .eps); convert "$f" "$b".png; done
```

The wildcard `*` in your attempt will expand to the list of all the files everywhere you use it, which isn't what you want. By using a loop variable `"$f"` instead you're only working with one file at a time.

You can also avoid calling `basename` and use:

```
for f in *.eps; do convert "$f" ${f%eps}png; done
```

This cuts off the `eps` from the end of the filename and adds `png` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.eps
do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    filename=${filename%.*}
    convert $file $filename.png
done
```

Hope it should work for you.

1. `for file in *.eps` gives the list of all files with .eps extension
2. `filename=$(basename "$file")` gives the original name of the file
3. `filename=${filename%.*}` remove the extension .eps
4. `convert $file $filename.png` convert file to .png extension

Answer (score 2):

Since I landed here while looking for a way to fix `convert: not authorized` without loosening the security policy for the entire system, I might as well present some improvements to @vaibhav-jain's answer.

First, if you're rasterizing EPS to PNG, here's how to skip ImageMagic and go straight to Ghostscript:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.eps; do
    gs -dSAFER -dEPSCrop -r300 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o "${file%.*}.png" "$file"
done
```

- `-dSAFER` puts Ghostscript in a sandboxed mode where Postscript code can only interact with the files you specified on the command line. (Yes, Postscript [is turing-complete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_NXz7I5dQc).)
- `-dEPSCrop` asks Ghostscript to not pad it out to the size of a printable page. ([details](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#EPS_parameters))
- If you're rasterizing EPS, you probably don't want the default of 72 DPI, so `-r300` specifies 300 DPI. ([details](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Output_resolution))
- `-sDEVICE` is how you pick the output format (See the [Devices section](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Devices.htm#JFIF) of the manual for other choices.)
- `-o` is a shorthand for `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=` ([details](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#File_output))

As for the other changes:

- It's unnecessary to strip off the leading path unless you're in a situation where you *don't* want the output files to go into the same folder as the input ones... in that case, however, you can replace `$(basename "$file")` with `${file##*/}` (strip characters up to and including last `/`) to stick to shell built-ins.
- If you're using Zsh and want to write a one-off one-liner, Zsh allows nesting substitutions, so `${${file##*/}%.*}` is valid.
- Just as a matter of style, I prefer `for ...; do` over putting `do` on its own line.
- Nothing in the script requires bash, so use `#!/bin/sh` in such situations and you'll get a lighter runtime environment ([dash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dash)) on Debian-based systems and be compatible with BSDs that don't install a `/bin/bash` by default.